# MSBuildCommunityTasks and Microsoft.Cpp folders are missed

Tags: .net, msbuild

I'm using MSBuild to build my projects (c++, c# and vb.net solutions) and want to configure my build machine (Windows 8 box).

But I have a problem. There's no **MSBuildCommunityTasks** and **Microsoft.Cpp** folders in
`c:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild` directory on build machine.

On the other hand, these 2 folders are present on my local Win7 box.

I'm getting build failures if these 2 folders are missed. So I have a simple question - what should I install on my Windows 8 build server to have **MSBuildCommunityTasks** and **Microsoft.Cpp** folders there?

I'm not sure that .NET Framework 4.0 does it. I've just tested it on my Win7 box when removed these folders manually first and then reinstalled .NET Framework 4.0 Full Package. Folders didn't appear in MsBuild folder after reinstall...

Comment: The .NET Framework does not support C++ and is not a vehicle to deploy C++ build tools.  You must install Visual Studio to get that.

Answer (score 2):

**MsBuildCommunityTasks** are a collection of MsBuild tasks managed by the user community.  Google for "MsBuild Community Tasks" to find the installer.

**The Microsoft.Cpp folder** was installed as part of your Visual Studio installation.  Open regedit.exe, then navigate to HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0.  Right click on the 4.0 folder, click "export", then ".txt" as the file type.  In the exported file, identify the time stamp that the key was written:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\MSBuild\ToolsVersions\4.0
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   10/23/2012 - 15:26
...
Value 7
  Name:            VCTargetsPath
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            $(MSBuildExtensionsPath32)\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\
```

Then view the list of installed programs on the Win7 computer, order by date, and see what was installed on that date.  Chances are you'll see many of the VC++ redistribute packages that are installed as pre-reqs to Visual Studio.

In summary: Download the MsBuildCommunitTasks package and install to your build server, and install any Visual Studio pre-requisites to get the Microsoft.Cpp folder to show up.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download and install MSBuild.Community.Tasks.msi from the following link
[MSBuild.Community.Tasks.msi download link](http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/servlets/ProjectDocumentList)
Install you related version either 3.5 or 4.0